# Are armies supposed to be limited by available plastic units?

Tags: game-of-thrones

During our first playthrough of this game we found that some of the plastic units in the game are very limited, based on the mustering capacity for various houses.

For instance, each house only has 2 plastic units for Siege Towers. When mustering, does this mean that a player's armies are limited to 2 siege towers in total, or just that the player needs additional tokens of some kind to identify them?

I can see both arguments. I can see an argument that units in the world are a finite resource, but I can also see a possibility that this is just a limit in the number of pieces provided and as long as players can track their armies and their armies conform to the supply rules they can have any composition they have the mustering capacity to create.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Armies *ARE* limited by the available plastic units**

According to the [rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/30/4f/304f72e3-4fe4-4f91-bfbe-75133161b092/va65_agot2_rulebook_web.pdf) for Game of Thrones Second Edition page 9 (emphasis mine):

*A mustered unit is taken from its player’s **unused** units, and placed directly into the area of the Castle or Stronghold that  provided the mustering point(s) to muster it.*

Because you must take the unit from your unused units when mustering, if the token is not in your unused unit pile then you can't muster it. Thus you are limited to the tokens in the box.

EDIT: As pointed out by @user2357112 supports Monica, the rules explicitly state you cannot use additional components on page 4:

*Exceeding the Components Provided: Each House is provided a limited of units, tokens, and cards. If a player is using all his components of a particular type, he may not bring additional components of that type into play. Units that are destroyed in combat (or removed from the board for any other reason) are available to be mustered again.*

Comment: Thank you so much for the wonderful clarification of that rule!!

Comment: More direct statement (from page 3): "Exceeding the Components Provided: Each house is provided a limited number of units, tokens, and cards. If a player is using all his components of a particular type, **he may not bring additional components of that type into play**. Units that are destroyed in combat (or removed from the board for any other reason) are available to be mustered again."

Comment: Didn't notice that @user2357112 . I'll add it to my answer for completeness.